# postfixでメール送信が行えない

Tags: postfix

SSHでログインし、mail関数を使用し、rootへメール送信しますがメールが届きません。
外部へのメールも同様です。

MTAは、postfixとdeovecotを使用しています。

/var/log/maillog/を確認した所、

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/maillog  
Jan 31 23:35:50 localhost postfix[2002]: dict_eval: const  no  
Jan 31 23:35:50 localhost postfix/postfix-script[2007]: error: unknown command: ''  
Jan 31 23:35:50 localhost postfix/postfix-script[2008]: fatal: usage: postfix start (or stop, reload, abort, flush, check, status, set-permissions, upgrade-configuration)  
Jan 31 23:39:36 localhost postfix/postfix-script[2110]: starting the Postfix mail system  
Jan 31 23:39:36 localhost postfix/master[2111]: fatal: /etc/postfix/master.cf: line 10: missing "transport type" field
```

とでておりました。
fatalで、transportとありますが、すみません何のことでしょうか。尚、今回新規のメールサーバ設置となり、『http://morizyun.github.io/blog/postfix-centos-sakura-vps-aws/』を参考にしました。

Answer (score 3):

ログの改行位置がうまく転写できていないようで、かなり見にくくなっていますが、この行:

> Jan 31 23:39:36 localhost postfix/master[2111]:
>   fatal:/etc/postfix/master.cf: line 10: missing "transport type" field

は、postfixの設定ファイルの一つであるmaster.cfのline 10:で「"transport type"フィールドが欠けている」ことを表しています。そのためにpostfixサーバが正常に起動していないものと思われます。

master.cfを編集する際に間違えて変なところまで書き換えてしまったということはないでしょうか。

```
#=  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  = 
# service type private unpriv chroot wakeup  maxproc command + args
#  name        (yes)   (yes)  (yes)  (never)  (100)
#=  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  = 
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -     smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1     pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0     cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1     qmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -     trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0     bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0     bounce
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0     flush
...
```

通常のmaster.cfは、上記のような内容のファイルで、"transport type"フィールドは`inet`,`fifo`,`unix`等が記載された2つ目のフィールドになります。エラーが報告された10行目前後がどうなっているかチェックしてみてください。postfixの設定ファイルでは行の先頭が空白かどうかは意味を持ちますので、そこら辺にも注意してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
master.cfを見直したら無事に送信動作まで確認できました！

Comment: 回答に「承認済み」のマークをして下さい。今までの質問全てが、承認済みになっていません。